# Beautifulsoup can't scrape an element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I tried to scraper the following site: https://www.footlocker.co.uk/en/all/new/

I want to scrape the price and the 'href' of the following element:

```
<span class=" fl-price--sale ">
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP">
    <meta itemprop="price" content="84.99"><span>£ 84,99</span>
</span>
```

and this (href):

```
<a href="https://www.footlocker.co.uk/en/p/adidas-performance-don-issue-2-men-shoes-92815?v=314102617504#!searchCategory=all" data-product-click-link="314102617504" data-hash-key="searchCategory" data-hash-url="https://www.footlocker.co.uk/en/p/adidas-performance-don-issue-2-men-shoes-92815?v=314102617504" data-testid="fl-product-details-link-314102617504">
```

I have tried this code:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

proxies = {'type':'ip:port'}

r= requests.get('https://www.footlocker.de/de/alle/new/', proxies=proxies)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')

# It doesn't find it...
for a in (soup.find_all('a')):
    try:
        if a['href'] == 'https://www.footlocker.co.uk/en/p/adidas-performance-don-issue-2-men-shoes-92815?v=314102617504#!searchCategory=all':
            print(a['href'])
    except:
        pass
# It don't find it...
for price in (soup.find_all('span', class_=' fl-price--sale ')):
    print(price.text)
```

I have tried to scrape with a proxy but he refuse to scrape the element (I think the HTML isn't right)

Thanks for your advices :-) (For education propose only)

Comment: Are you sure `' fl-price--sale '` is supposed to have spaces at the beginning and end?

Comment: Yes I have check without spaces, you can check on the link.

Comment: Also, `requests.get()` does not handle javascript.  If the page has javascript that dynamically creates the element you're looking for, then `requests` won't work for you.

Comment: and what I have to do for scrape javascript dynamic elements?

Comment: You'd have to use something that works like a real browser, such as Selenium.

Comment: I know but it isn't the correct way for my bot.... I have to make this with bs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get names, links and prices of the products, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.footlocker.co.uk/INTERSHOP/web/FLE/Footlocker-Footlocker_GB-Site/en_GB/-/GBP/ViewStandardCatalog-ProductPagingAjax?SearchParameter=____&sale=new&MultiCategoryPathAssignment=all&PageNumber={}'

for page in range(3):  # <--- increase the number of pages here
    print('Page {}...'.format(page))
    data = requests.get(url.format(page)).json()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data['content'], 'html.parser')

    for d in soup.select('[data-request]'):
        s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(d['data-request']).json()['content'], 'html.parser')
        
        print(s.select_one('[itemprop="name"]').text)
        print(s.select_one('[itemprop="price"]')['content'], s.select_one('[itemprop="priceCurrency"]')['content'])
        print(s.a['href'])
        print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Page 0...
adidas Performance Don Issue 2 - Men Shoes
84.99 GBP
https://www.footlocker.co.uk/en/p/adidas-performance-don-issue-2-men-shoes-92815?v=314102617504
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nike Air Force 1 Crater - Women Shoes
94.99 GBP
https://www.footlocker.co.uk/en/p/nike-air-force-1-crater-women-shoes-98071?v=315349054502
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jordan Jumpmcn Cl Iii Camo - Baby Tracksuits
39.99 GBP
https://www.footlocker.co.uk/en/p/jordan-jumpmcn-cl-iii-camo-baby-tracksuits-91611?v=318280390044
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jordan 13 Retro - Grade School Shoes
99.99 GBP
https://www.footlocker.co.uk/en/p/jordan-13-retro-grade-school-shoes-952?v=316701533404
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST

Comment: But where did you find the url?

Comment: @MatteoBianchi If you click on `Load More` then you see in Chrome/Firefox developer tools (Network tab) the URL